# Get Rails to save child records that were built using custom setter methods (instead of accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built an application that helps users monitor a variety of financial products.

On about 6-10 different models that each track different types of financial products (credit cards, savings accounts, etc.), I've previously had a `balance` column (to store the user's current balance) and a `repayments` column to store the user's average contributions to the account over time.

I'd now like to store historical balance updates, and I think the best way to do that is create a seperate `balance` model that can `belongs_to` all these models through a polymorphic relationship. Then each account can `has_many` balances at different points in history, and I can easily pull out the users most recent `balance`.

I like this solution, **BUT** I have a bunch of customised user forms for creating/editing the accounts with `balance` fields, `repayments` fields, and a few other fields that will be abstracted out into a `Balance` model. I didn't want to spend hours going through these forms and changing the fields to accomodate the new nested structure. Instead, I've created a bunch of helper methods that will handle all the backend logic so that none of my views need to interact with my model differently, like so:

```
#creditcard_account.rb
  has_many :balances, :as => :balanceable, :dependent => :destroy

  def latest_balance
    balances.order("created_at DESC").first
  end

  def new_balance
    @new_balance ||= balances.build
  end

  def balance=(input_balance)
    new_balance.amount = input_balance
  end

  def balance
    new_balance.balance || (latest_balance? ? self.latest_balance.amount : nil)
  end

  def repayment_amount=(input_repayment_amount)
    new_balance.contribution_amount = input_repayment_amount
  end

  def repayment_amount
    new_balance.contribution_amount || (latest_balance ?  latest_balance.contribution_amount : nil)
  end

  def repayment_period=(input_repayment_period)
    new_balance.contribution_period = input_repayment_period
  end

  def repayment_period
    new_balance.contribution_period || (latest_balance ?  latest_balance.contribution_period : nil)
  end
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
This works fine, **EXCEPT** @new_balance does not get saved if no actual attributes of the relevant `creditcard_account` changed. That is, Rails Dirty Model approach doesn't know that I've created a child and the parent needs to be saved.

**How can I tell Rails that I've created a child for this model and that the model (and it's child) need to be saved?**

If it's important, all the forms in question actually have `creditcard_account` as a nested `fields_for` in a `form_for :user`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forcing the parent to save by setting the updated_at attribute of the parent to Time.now, so that the parent is flagged as `changed?` and is therefore saved (with its children):

```
  def balance=(input_balance)
    new_balance.amount = input_balance
    self.updated_at = Time.now
  end

  def repayment_amount=(input_repayment_amount)
    new_balance.contribution_amount = input_repayment_amount
    self.updated_at = Time.now
  end

  def repayment_period=(input_repayment_period)
    new_balance.contribution_period = input_repayment_period
    self.updated_at = Time.now
  end
```

For anyone attempting something similar, be aware that this my approach has raised other problems: for example, validation on these virtual attributes is pretty much broken.